# java subclass prints parameter default values instead of assigned values

Tags: java, inheritance

I am doing some reading and practice to better understand java inheritance. When I run the Lion class below, it prints out `0 and null`. I think it should rather print out the parameters values i.e. `30 and roars`. what I am doing wrong?

```
public class Animal {

    int numTeeth;

    public Animal(int numTeeth) {
        numTeeth = this.numTeeth;
    }

    public int getNumTeeth() {
        return numTeeth;
    }   
    public void setNumTeeth(int numTeeth) {
        this.numTeeth = numTeeth;       
    }
}


public class Lion extends Animal {

    String sound;

    public Lion(int numTeeth, String sound) 
    {
        super(numTeeth);
        sound = this.sound;
    }

    public String getSound() {          
        return sound;
    }

    public void setSound(String sound) {        
        this.sound = sound;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Lion simba = new Lion(30, "roars");     
        System.out.println(simba.getNumTeeth());
        System.out.println(simba.getSound());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code:

```
public Scratch(int numTeeth) {
    numTeeth = this.numTeeth;
}
```

Is doing the opposite of what you intend it to do (overwriting the parameter with the default value in the instance field). It should be:

```
public Scratch(int numTeeth) {
    this.numTeeth = numTeeth;
}
```

When local variables reuse an an instance field's name, qualify the instance variable name with `this` or class name if it's static.

To help yourself prevent this in future, you could make your input parameters final, which will simply cause your original code not to compile.

```
public Scratch(final int numTeeth) {
    this.numTeeth = numTeeth;
}
```

The same applies to the sound variable too.

Answer (score 4):

Your field assignments are the wrong way around, it should be

```
this.numTeeth = numTeeth;
```

and

```
this.sound = sound;
```

Otherwise you assign the field to the local variable, which does not make much sense.

Answer (score 0):

When you're assigning `numTeeth` or `sound` - compiler sees the most close local variable with the same name. When you specify `this.sound` - it means you want to access the field of current object.
So, when you're doing `numTeeth = this.numTeeth` - you're assigning the value of your field to the local variable. You have to swap it - `this.numTeeth = numTeeth` - so, you're assigning the value of the local variable(parameter) to the field.

Also, to avoid such mistakes, you can use **Hungarian notation** or underline the field names:

```
class Test {
    int mCount;
    //or
    int _count;

    Test(int count) {
        _count = count;
        mCount = count;
    }
}
```